# Where can you explain why you chose the answer you chose?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer

I recently accepted an answer to my question, but I would like to explain why I chose it, to the next person who is asking the same question?

Is it acceptable to edit your question and add at the bottom, a place to reflect why you chose the answer you chose?

Or should you comment the answer, and explain there?

This is especially important if there are multiple correct solutions, and you want to explain why you chose the one you did.

Comment: @Yannis that's what I am asking... is it better to place that in a comment on the answer or edit the question and put it at the end of it.

Comment: A comment under the accepted answer or the question would be preferable. Do not edit the question, the question's text should be all about... the question ;) Adding meta commentary like that in the question's text will only serve to confuse future searches (you'd be adding a set of keywords to the text that don't really have much to do with the actual question).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add it as a comment to the accepted answer. People will look there when they see the answer has been accepted.

If you add it to the question text, people may not notice that your question has changed. They may not see your updated text.

Answer (score 7):

> I would like to explain why I chose it, to the next person who is asking the same question?

Along side with providing users with answers to *their* questions, Stack is designed to provide a future reference for many users. In order to achieve this, you have to retain a decent structured Q&A, so the question, comments and answer(s) have to be precise in their usage, so are all easily understood and clear throughout.

This ensures other people wanting an answer on the same question can read through the *thread* in its entirety and quite easily understand due to a decent structure, and so obtain a potential resolve to their issue without too much fuss.

- *The question* should remain solely the question, when read it should
  outline what is being asked and nothing else (ie no "thanks to Steve,
  main man" or "All solved now");
- *Question comments* should be relating to finding an answer for the question. They
  are often *pointers* to things to try, and sometimes are a *snippet answer* ("have you tried" etc) which can be as useful as an answer to other visitors if it hits their scenario problem;
- *Answer(s)* should be concise and clear replies directly answering
  the question, with possibly other relevant info;
- *Answer comments* should be relating to that specific answer, adding a bit more info, or pointing out a potential issue, etc;

> Where can you explain why you chose the answer you chose?

There is no real need as your selecting a chosen answer means "this is the answer that answered your question".
Anyone else finding your question with the same/similar issue will likely find the chosen answer also helpful, if not then the question wasn't outlining a similar problem or was badly written/worded.

If you feel the need, however, put it in the comments on the answer you chose. I don't see the need, but this would be the best place.

Comment: I agree completely. In other words, you have to first understand, why is it that you want to explain why you chose the answer that you chose and whether anybody would want to go so deeply into your thought process. Any examples of questions where such an explanation would be helpful?